# How to use HTML5 history with Ajax app API calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-history

I have an embeddable JavScript widget I have made that talks to a WordPress Plugin I made. Basically the widget calls out out to some custom WP API endpoints and gets the JSON back then builds a feed of products that are categories. Each click on category drills down to next via a new API call to get new data.

It all works, yay, but I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to make browser back button work.

Note that I do not care if it can be an easy hashbang or whatever, this does not need to be bookmarkable or google crawlable.

Tutorials I find just say pushState is an object, but of what?

My click handler looks like this,

```
$('#sqsl_products').on('click', '.ssla-embed-link',  function( e ) {
   e.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this),
          linkType = link.attr('data-link_type'),
          linkId = link.attr('data-link_id');

          switch( linkType ) {
              case 'categories':
                  getCategories( linkId );
                  break;
              case 'products':
                  getProducts( linkId );
                  break;
              case 'product':
                  getProduct( linkId );
                  break;
          }

});
```

Each case goes to a different ajax call, that gets the data and outputs it, example:

```
function getCategories( id ) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiUrl + '/categories',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(domTag).prepend('<div class="ssla-loading-top"></div>');
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { categories: id },
    })
    .done(function( response ) {
        var catList = '<ul>';
        var brand = response.brand;
        $.each(response.data, function () {
            catList += '<li><a data-link_type=' + this.type + ' data-link_id=' + this.id + ' class="ssla-embed-link" href="#' + this.id + '"><img src="'+this.image+'"/>' + this.name + '</a></li>';
        });
        catList += '</ul>';
        $(domTag).removeClass().addClass( 'ssla-' + brand + ' ssla-categories' ).html(catList);
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR ) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
        $(domTag).removeClass().addClass('ssla-error').html(json.message);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });
}
```

Now would pushState happen in the `.done()` chain, and if so what gets added there?

Any tips are greatly appreciated, thank you!

**update**

Got it working-ish with this

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function( e ) {

    var hash = document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
    var split = hash.split('-');
    if ( split.length < 2 ) {
        return;
    }
    var linkType = split[0];
    var linkId = split[1];

    console.log(linkType);
    console.log(linkId);

      switch( linkType ) {
          case 'categories':
              getCategories( linkId );
              break;
          case 'products':
              getProducts( linkId );
              break;
          case 'product':
              getProduct( linkId );
              break;
      }
});
```

However fails when going back to "first" page. Is this because it is not handled via a hash and is initially loaded via an ajax call on doc ready?

Comment: Call the function manually the first time. It `var hashFn = function() {...}`. `$(window).on('hashchange', hashFn)`. `hashFn()`. Then if linkType/linkId are not set, (Where you're doing `if split.length < 2`), add code for a default.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add `window.location.hash = "#categories-" + id;` instead of the switch statement.

```js
/*switch (linkType) {
    case 'categories':
        getCategories(linkId);
        break;
    case 'products':
        getProducts(linkId);
        break;
    case 'product':
        getProduct(linkId);
        break;
}*/
//Replace the switch function. This will update the url to something like #categories-1 which will fire the event below
window.location.hash = '#' + linkType + '-' + linkId;
//Optionally, you can just set the href of the URL's to #categories-1 instead of using this function at all.
```

Step 2: Add an `onhashchange` handler which will fire any time the hash (ie. #categories-1) changes in the URL:

```js
$(window).on('hashchange', function( e ) {
      let split = window.location.split('-');
      if ( split.length < 2 )
         return;

      var linkType = split[0];
      var linkId = split[1];

      switch( linkType ) {
          case 'categories':
              getCategories( linkId );
              break;
          case 'products':
              getProducts( linkId );
              break;
          case 'product':
              getProduct( linkId );
              break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try. What is `let` ?

Comment: Thanks for this start, got me in a right direction I think, updated code with new question :)